# Eclipse CDT, Can't use debugger (Always stuck on 89% process)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

If I run debugger then it gets stuck on 89% process...
It shows

```
 Launching : Configuring GDB Aborting configuring GDB
```

I just wanted to see the debugger is working so all I have is

```
printf("debug test");
```

in main function..
Do you guys know what the problem is?

Comment: Did you use cdt on which platform?

Comment: @LCYSoft Currently I have issue with the same symptoms. Whenever I start debugging even simple Java app in eclipse, progress goes to 89% and nothings happens after that. It seems that you have solved this issue. Could you say: where can I download this libexpat-1.dll, where should I place it and how can I check that problem appears because of this DLL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello 
after experiencing the same, it appeared gdb was missing access to some dll (libexpat-1.dll).
putting it in the current path corrected the problem.
in order to check this, try invoking gdb from the command prompt

all the best

olivier

Answer (score 9):

I have spent quite some time on this. It's really annoying and the solution is stupid to me:

**Environment:**

Mac + Eclipse + gdb (ggdb downloaded from macports).

**Symptom:**

Debugging hangs at 100% at startup. `launching gdb aborting configuring gdb`.

**Solution: run as root**

`sudo /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse`

Comment: +1 worked for me too. I guess that sudo is not the best solution here. Maybe theres just a certain group membership you would have to have as the resp. user in order for it to work.

Comment: For me eclipse is installed in /Users/[Username]/eclipse/cpp-oxygen/Eclipse.app Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer lies in codesigning, and the problem originates with the system security changes introduced by Apple. Please see [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38882835/2573242), which fixed the same issue for me. Launching Eclipse with `sudo` ([as recommended above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38574179/2573242)) should probably be discouraged due to potential risks with your IDE going haywire with root permissions.

Comment: I've signed the gdb executable (and verified it with `codesign --verify --verbose ./arm-none-eabi-gdb`), however, it still doesn't work, still the same error...

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this error on Mac Mavericks. After `which gdb` I figured out that the path set in Eclipse Debug Configuration is not correct. Somehow I mistakenly set it to `/usr/local/bin/gdb` which actually should be `/usr/bin/gdb`