# gdb error- File not in executable format: File format not recognized

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debugging, gdb

I am trying to debug a certain program called xdf with gdb but when i run gdb xdf, i get the following error:

```
"/home/nealtitusthomas/X-ray_astronomy/heasoft-6.24/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.27/bin/xdf": not in executable format: File format not recognized
```

The program is symbolically linked and the output of `file /home/nealtitusthomas/X-ray_astronomy/heasoft-6.24/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.27/bin/xdf` is:

```
/home/nealtitusthomas/X-ray_astronomy/heasoft-6.24/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.27/bin/xdf: symbolic link to ../../ftools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.27/bin/xdf
```

The solution given here [gdb error not in executable format: File format not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47639685/gdb-error-not-in-executable-format-file-format-not-recognized) says that it is because the gdb installed is a 32 bit version and the program is 64 bit. However, my gdb installation is 64 bit. This is confirmed by the following:

```
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
```

Comment: And... what format is `../../ftools/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.27/bin/xdf`?

Comment: It is a POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to use GDB on a shell script. Just like it's trying to tell you, GDB doesn't know what to do with that.

Answer (score 2):

> the output of `file /home/nealti...`

In general, you almost always should use `file -L /home/...` instead -- that command will dereference any symbolic links, and tell you what the file is *after* resolving all the symlinks.

> `POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable`

You are trying to debug a shell script. GDB has no idea how to do that.

You need to look *inside* that shell script (with an editor of your choice), find out what *actual* binary it eventually invokes, and debug that.

The wrapper shell scripts typically look something like this:

```
 #!/bin/sh
... some code to figure out installation directory (e.g. INSTALL_DIR)
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$INSTALL_DIR/lib64:..."

# Now invoke the binary:
exec "$INSTALL_DIR/bin/xdf.exe" "$@"
```

What you'll want to do is replace the last line with:

```
exec /usr/bin/gdb --args "$INSTALL_DIR/bin/xdf.exe" "$@"
```

and run your `xdf` shell script normally. It will now invoke gdb auto-magically.

Comment: I have found that the original script is a tcl script which resides in **/home/nealtitusthomas/X-ray_astronomy/heasoft-6.24/ftools/BLD/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.27/lib/xtcl/.xdfrc**
However, i am unable to get gdb to run it. I get a _not in executable format_ error.