# Eclipse Dev for C: Debugger Problem - Failed to execute MI command

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging

My .c file compiles and runs just fine.

I have tried going into Debug Config -> Debugger and making sure the right gdb file was there.

I constantly get this error when I try to run the debugger:

Error in final launch sequence:

Failed to execute MI command:
-file-exec-and-symbols "C:/Users/Taha/Desktop/Taha's Docs/Eclipse Dev/Assignment5/Debug/Assignment5.exe"
Error message from debugger back end:
"C:/Users/Taha/Desktop/Taha's Docs/Eclipse Dev/Assignment5/Debug/Assignment5.exe": not in executable format: File format not recognized

I have searched around for a long time, please help!

Comment: Looks like your gdb is not matching the architecture you are compiling for.

Comment: How can I check that and update it if I need to?

Comment: there might be a bug in gdb, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47639685/gdb-error-not-in-executable-format-file-format-not-recognized